# php windows undefined constant error - working on linux?

Tags: php

I have working code I developed for a linux server that when I have tested locally using WAMP have started to get strange Xdebug errors of the form

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant fullName - assumed 'fullName'
```

The code is...

```
$allVars = array(
    fullName=>$fullName, 
    telephone=>$telephone,
    email=>$email,

    fAddr=>$fAddr,
    tAddr=>$tAddr,
    sngRtnSelect=>$sngRtnSelect,
    oDate=>$oDate,
    rDate=>$rDate,
    tAdditional=>$tAdditional,
    noPassengers=>$noPassangers,
    vehicleType=>$vehicleType,
    distance=>$distance,
    priceTot=>$finalPrice

);
```

I thought the above was a straight forward array definition. Could anyone shed light on why such errors are appearing on WAMP and not the linux server?

If I have missed something obvious, then my apologies, however this is the identical code that worked on the linux/apache server. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are defining a string key then you should put it inside quotes. Like this:

```
$arr = array ( 'some_key' => 'some_value' )
```

However, when you are working with integers you should not use quotes, otherwise you'll create a string.

```
$arry = array ( '0' => 'this is a string key because it has quotes around.', 
                 0  => 'this is an integer key because it has not quotes around.');
```

By the way, when you do not use quotes for a string value, it means that you refer to a defined variable.

```
define ( 'name', 'Savas Vedova' );
echo name; // this will print Savas Vedova to the screen.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. Peculiar however that the linux PHP version was more forgiving. Cheers.

Comment: @GHarping You're welcome. Well, I am not sure whether it is because linux is more forgiving but rather I believe that your settings were different than the other version you were using. Check your error_reporting settings in your php.ini to see whether they are similar with the other version.

Answer (score 1):

```
$allVars = array(
'fullName'=>$fullName, 
'telephone'=>$telephone,
'email'=>$email
```

);

you should use ' <= this ;)

Answer (score 0):

Both right, use quotes. Also, that is NOT an error but a **Notice**. Surely you have a php.ini with error_reporting including E_NOTICE, so the notices show up (in the end, PHP interpreter assumed the right thing, even if you did it wrong!)  [but please, please, do it right, don't be lazy!!! :P]

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

perhaps, WAMP default is less forgiving than linux default

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question...

> Could anyone shed light on why such errors are appearing on WAMP and not the linux server?

Your servers have different levels of error reporting defined in their configuration files.

The message in question is an `E_NOTICE` level error.

See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php